# Placing div layers with javascript move when browser is resized but it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a small app to learn Python/Flask in web dev but the issue I am having is related to CSS / javascript and I can't figure it out.  Let's see it in action:

1. Go to http://sareon.pythonanywhere.com/
2. enter game ID "20234"
3. Click a few times on the image on the left to create a few new div layer / images
4. Resize your browser and watch as the newly created images dont stay where you clicked them.

I am not sure how to fix this.

I thought it was because of the .puck CSS which has its position as absolute.  Changing it to relative and things dont match up to where you click but they dont move when you resize the browser.  Static makes everything line up along the side of the image regardless of where you click.  Fixed does the same thing as absolute.

So I am not sure how to go about figuring this out

Comment: Its mostly because of the `margin: auto` values, but using a relative parent will fix this regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're positioning each of the .puck elements "absolutely". The origin (left: 0; top: 0) value must come from one of the .puck's parent elements. Seeing as none of the parent elements of .puck have any 'position' properties clearly defined, it will default to the top left of your browsers window.

The fix? Add a 'position: relative' to the #hockeyRinkHome element. This way, when the .puck elements are being positioned, it traverses up only one div to the #hockeyRinkHome element and decides to base it's absolute location off of that element. It's top left corner becomes the new (left: 0; top: 0).

You will have to re-adjust your calculations for placing each .puck. However it will now always remain steady and constant.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing them in a `position: relative` container and each puck should be then still `position: absolute`.

Comment: Make sure that when you place the puck down, though, that you use the difference of the parent element's `offsetTop` from the `top` value and the `offsetLeft` from the `left` value.

Comment: Yeah this is the issue.  Doing what Daniel says makes it so they dont move but now they aren's sitting down where you click but rather down and to the left a bunch.